# Running an AUv3 extension in standalone mode does not initialize the AudioUnit class

Tags: ios, swift, audiounit, auv3

I've been developing an AUv3 plugin and running it inside a host as an extension has been fine, but I'm trying to make it run in standalone mode and struggling. My project structure is based on the Xcode template project.

I've put a print to the console in the AUAudioUnit subclass's initializer and it shows up in the console when running inside a host, but when I run in standalone, the initializer doesn't run and it seems that the AudioUnit subclass isn't being initialized at all. It's confusing because the UI *does* load, but it seemingly is not connected to the AudioUnit (which is not there at all).

It seems like the bare minimum of this template would be for standalone operation to properly load the AudioUnit but it doesn't do that out of the box. If someone could explain what modification is required for the simple Xcode AUv3 template, I could apply it to my project.